# Unit testing mfc application backed with oracle?

Tags: oracle, unit-testing, mfc, googletest

App:MFC backed by oracle
Unit testing framework:googletest
I am going to unit testing the code that will be added here on to the project.Unit testing framework is googletest. I am new to unit testing. Is googletest is ok for my application how can I get started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to get started with something simple. Find some code which you don't understand or which caused trouble in the past and write a test for that. Ideally, this code should be a single method which doesn't need a database or web server. Avoid tests which cover more than a single thing until you've learned how to write tests (at that time, you'll automatically avoid tests like that because they are brittle and, more often than not, they cause more problems than they solve).